# Need example to understand simple random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions

let me define it first,
let $(\Omega,S,P)$ be a probability measure.A random variable $X$ is said to be simple if it can be written as $X(\omega)$=$\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}I_{A_{i}}(\omega)$ where $\omega\in \Omega$ and $I_{A_{i}}(\omega)=1$ if $\omega\in A_i$ and is 0 if $\omega \not\in \Omega$.I understood the definition but I need one example in probability space to understand it more clearly.

Comment: A simple r.v. is just a  r.v. which assumes only finite number of values. Do you know any such?

Comment: if I toss a coin once then my $\Omega$={$H, T$} and define my random variable $X$=number of heads. Is it a correct example?

Comment: Yes, it is a good example.

Comment: Thanks,now I understood it.

Answer (score 0):

*Commenting got too long so i'm turning it into an answer*

*EDIT: Clarifications*

To be more precise, take a simple case. You toss a coin, if heads you gain 50, if tails you lose 2000 because you are getting scammed. Imagine $X$ to be your gains.

Now, $ \Omega := \{ H, T \} $ is the space of all basic outcomes so that $\omega$ is either $H$ or $T$. You can write $X$ as :

\begin{equation}
X(\omega) = 50I_{ \{ H \} }(\omega) - 2000 I_{ \{ T \} }(\omega)
\end{equation}

so that for example $X(H) = 50$.

While your example is correct, i feel like picking $ X=$ number of heads can be misleading in that particular case. Because $\Omega = \{H,T\}$ describes only one toss X can be either 0 or 1 which is indeed a simple variable but then calling it the number of heads alludes to having multiples tosses.

If you wanted to have 5 tosses. You could write say $\Omega' = \{H,T\}^5$ for 5 tosses, and the basic events would be something like $\omega' = (H,H,H,T,H)$ and define $X'$ as the intended number of heads.